When I upload invalid file it throw several error and it's due to 'handleFileChange Function' It recalling many time on just upload a 1 item
When I upload invalid file it throw several error and it's due to 'handleFileChange Function' It recalling many time on just upload a 1 item and I want one error


import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from '@wordpress/element';
import { createRoot } from '@wordpress/element';
import {
    ProForm,
    ProFormDateRangePicker,
    ProFormText,
    ProFormTextArea,
    ProFormSelect,
    ProFormUploadDragger
} from '@ant-design/pro-components';
import { Col, Row, message, ConfigProvider, Alert, Space } from 'antd';
import apiFetch from '@wordpress/api-fetch';
import enUS from 'antd/lib/locale/en_US';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import DraggableMarkerMap from './google-maps/DraggableMarkerMap';

const TeacherDealForm = () => {
    const formRef = useRef();
    const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([]);
    const [uploadedFileName, setUploadedFileName] = useState('');
    const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false);
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
    const [googleMapPosition, setGoogleMapPosition] = useState({
        lat: parseFloat(sa_edurp_teacher_deal_form_localized_objects?.google_map_location?.lat),
        lng: parseFloat(sa_edurp_teacher_deal_form_localized_objects?.google_map_location?.long),
    });
    const [featureMediaID, setFeatureMediaID] = useState(null);
    const [isUploading, setIsUploading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        apiFetch({
            path: '/wp/v2/teacher_deal_category?hide_empty=0',
            method: 'GET',
        })
            .then((response) => {
                setCategories(response);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error fetching categories:', error);
            });
    }, []);

    const handleFinish = async (values) => {
        try {
            const userId = parseInt(sa_edurp_teacher_deal_form_localized_objects.user_id, 10);
            const teacherDealsId = parseInt(sa_edurp_teacher_deal_form_localized_objects.current_post_id, 10);

            const [startDate, endDate] = values.dateRange || [];
            const formattedStartDate = startDate ? dayjs(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') : null;
            const formattedEndDate = endDate ? dayjs(endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') : null;

            const response = await fetch('/wp-json/wp/v2/teacher_deal/', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    title: values.title,
                    content: values.detail,
                    user_id: userId,
                    teacher_deals_id: teacherDealsId,
                    featured_media_id: featureMediaID,
                    meta: {
                        contact_filermation: values.contactInfo,
                        teacher_deal_form_URL: values.url,
                        teacher_deal_form_location: values.location,
                        validity_start_date: formattedStartDate,
                        validity_end_date: formattedEndDate,
                        teacher_deal_form_location_lat: googleMapPosition.lat,
                        teacher_deal_form_location_long: googleMapPosition.lng,
                        who_can_avail_this_deal: values.who_can_avail_this_deal,
                    },
                    categories: [values.category],
                }),
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                message.success('Application submitted successfully');
                formRef.current.resetFields();
                setShowAlert(false);
                setFileList([]);
                return true;
            } else {
                const errorData = await response.json();
                message.error('Failed to submit application: ' + errorData.message);
                return false;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            message.error('An error occurred while submitting the application.');
            return false;
        }
    };

    const handleFileChange = async ({ file, fileList: newFileList }) => {
        console.log('File Change Triggered 1');
        if (isUploading) return;

        const currentFile = newFileList[0];
        setIsUploading(true);

        if (!currentFile) {
            setFileList([]);
            setShowAlert(false);
            setIsUploading(false);
            return;
        }

        // Validate file type and size
        const isJpgOrPng = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png'].includes(currentFile.type);
        const isLt10M = currentFile.size / 1024 / 1024 <= 10;

        if (!isJpgOrPng || !isLt10M) {
            message.error(
                !isJpgOrPng 
                ? 'You can only upload JPG/PNG images!' 
                : 'Image must be smaller than 10MB!'
            );
            setFileList([]);
            setShowAlert(false);
            setIsUploading(false);
            return;
        }

        // Process valid image upload
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', currentFile.originFileObj);

        try {
            const response = await apiFetch({
                path: '/wp/v2/media',
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
            });

            if (response.id) {
                setFeatureMediaID(response.id);
                setUploadedFileName(currentFile.name);
                setShowAlert(true);
                setFileList([currentFile]);
            } else {
                message.error('Failed to upload image. Please try again.');
                setFileList([]);
                setShowAlert(false);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            message.error('An error occurred while uploading the image.');
            setFileList([]);
            setShowAlert(false);
        } finally {
            setIsUploading(false);
        }
    };

    return (
        <ConfigProvider locale={enUS}>
            <ProForm
                formRef={formRef}
                onFinish={handleFinish}
            >
                <ProFormText
                    name="title"
                    label="Deal Title:"
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please enter deal title' }]}
                />
                <ProFormTextArea
                    name="detail"
                    label="Details:"
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please enter details' }]}
                />
                <ProFormSelect
                    name="category"
                    label="Teacher Deal Category"
                    options={categories.map((category) => ({
                        label: category.name,
                        value: category.id,
                    }))}
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please select a category!' }]}
                />
                <ProFormUploadDragger
                    title="Upload Image"
                    name="dragger"
                    label="Upload Image:"
                    description="jpeg png"
                    // fileList={fileList}
                    onChange={
                        handleFileChange
                    } 
                    fieldProps={{
                        maxCount: 1,
                        accept: '.jpeg,.png',
                        showUploadList: false,
                    }}
                    rules={[
                        {
                            required: true,
                            message: 'Please upload a file!',
                        },
                    ]}
                    // hasFeedback
                />
                {showAlert && (
                    <Space
                        direction="vertical"
                        style={{ width: '100%' }}
                    >
                        <Alert
                            message={`File ${uploadedFileName} uploaded successfully!`}
                            type="success"
                            showIcon
                            closable
                            onClose={() => setShowAlert(false)}
                        />
                        <br />
                    </Space>
                )}
                <Row gutter={16}>
                    <Col span={12}>
                        <ProFormDateRangePicker
                            name="dateRange"
                            label="Validity:"
                            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please enter validity' }]}
                        />
                    </Col>
                    <Col span={12}>
                        <ProFormText
                            name="who_can_avail_this_deal"
                            label="Who can avail this deal:"
                            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please enter who can avail this deal' }]}
                        />
                    </Col>
                    <Col span={12}>
                        <ProFormText
                            name="contactInfo"
                            label="Contact Information:"
                            placeholder="123-456789"
                            rules={[
                                { required: true, message: 'Please input your contact information' },
                                { pattern: /^[0-9]*$/, message: 'Contact information must be numbers only' },
                            ]}
                        />
                    </Col>
                    <Col span={12}>
                        <ProFormText
                            name="url"
                            label="URL"
                            placeholder="https://www.google.com/"
                            rules={[
                                { required: true, message: 'Please input the URL' },
                                { type: 'url', message: 'Please input a valid URL' },
                            ]}
                        />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <div className="map">
                    <DraggableMarkerMap
                        initialCoords={googleMapPosition}
                        onPositionChange={(newPosition) => {
                            setGoogleMapPosition(newPosition);
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
            </ProForm>
        </ConfigProvider>
    );
};

createRoot(document.getElementById('sa-edurp-teacher-deal-form')).render(
    <TeacherDealForm />
);



When I upload invalid file it throw several error and it's due to 'handleFileChange Function' It recalling many time on just upload a 1 item and I want one error
